# Inception-v3 transfer learning 'freezing' layers

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, convolution

I have used the Inception-v3 network for transfer learning. The first 172 layers in the network are 'frozen'. But the Inception-v3 network only has 48 layers. Where did the 'extra' layers come from?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually inception module is bit more complicated. It doesn't have single branch. Later those multiple branches are concatenated into single branch. If you list all layers in keras you get this:

```
[ 1 ]  <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f94c6b95750>
[ 2 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c6577610>
[ 3 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c65778d0>
[ 4 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c6577a90>
[ 5 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c6900f50>
[ 6 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c6878bd0>
[ 7 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c690e750>
[ 8 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c68d1e10>
[ 9 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c68d1f10>
[ 10 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c6652b90>
[ 11 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f94c6319390>
[ 12 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c6309490>
[ 13 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c62cea50>
[ 14 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c628b890>
[ 15 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c62a4490>
[ 16 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c62b7750>
[ 17 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c626ac50>
[ 18 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f94c6226a10>
[ 19 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c6064850>
[ 20 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c6076b10>
[ 21 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c602bf10>
[ 22 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c6146ad0>
[ 23 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5ff7710>
[ 24 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c6155d90>
[ 25 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5f889d0>
[ 26 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c6119e90>
[ 27 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5fbaed0>
[ 28 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c5e88850>
[ 29 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c62329d0>
[ 30 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c60d4990>
[ 31 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5f77b50>
[ 32 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5e962d0>
[ 33 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c6232350>
[ 34 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c60e6c50>
[ 35 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5f77750>
[ 36 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5e5a890>
[ 37 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c619cf90>
[ 38 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c60ac8d0>
[ 39 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5ec8b10>
[ 40 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5e0ca90>
[ 41 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c5e24890>
[ 42 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5c4f990>
[ 43 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5c4f590>
[ 44 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5c22310>
[ 45 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5db9910>
[ 46 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5bde710>
[ 47 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5d49ad0>
[ 48 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5bde310>
[ 49 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5d0df10>
[ 50 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5bb3750>
[ 51 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c5a81c50>
[ 52 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5e39a50>
[ 53 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5cc9690>
[ 54 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5b6fe90>
[ 55 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5af5dd0>
[ 56 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5e19a10>
[ 57 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5cdd850>
[ 58 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5b6fed0>
[ 59 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5a44850>
[ 60 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5d9eb10>
[ 61 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5c90c50>
[ 62 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5ac54d0>
[ 63 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5a66710>
[ 64 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c5a157d0>
[ 65 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c589aad0>
[ 66 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5854350>
[ 67 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c581b390>
[ 68 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c59a4850>
[ 69 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c57d5b10>
[ 70 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c59a4450>
[ 71 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c57e9cd0>
[ 72 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c596ae90>
[ 73 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c57aed90>
[ 74 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c56fb610>
[ 75 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5a153d0>
[ 76 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c59365d0>
[ 77 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5769890>
[ 78 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c56eec50>
[ 79 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5a237d0>
[ 80 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c59361d0>
[ 81 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c577aa50>
[ 82 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c56bd210>
[ 83 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5995090>
[ 84 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c588b610>
[ 85 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c56c1e90>
[ 86 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c566edd0>
[ 87 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c560dbd0>
[ 88 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c559ec50>
[ 89 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c55ae7d0>
[ 90 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5573250>
[ 91 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c552d9d0>
[ 92 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c54c0b90>
[ 93 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5484fd0>
[ 94 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c561dd90>
[ 95 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5441750>
[ 96 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c567fd50>
[ 97 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5452910>
[ 98 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5581e50>
[ 99 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5408d10>
[ 100 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f94c53c6a50>
[ 101 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c53d5a50>
[ 102 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5196690>
[ 103 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c51ab850>
[ 104 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c515dc50>
[ 105 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c511b990>
[ 106 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c511b590>
[ 107 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c50ee310>
[ 108 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c53743d0>
[ 109 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c50ae710>
[ 110 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5366e10>
[ 111 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c50ae310>
[ 112 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5337410>
[ 113 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5001750>
[ 114 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c52f4b90>
[ 115 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4fc2e90>
[ 116 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5284d50>
[ 117 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4fc2ed0>
[ 118 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c524b190>
[ 119 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4f924d0>
[ 120 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c4ed3f50>
[ 121 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c53d54d0>
[ 122 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c5204910>
[ 123 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4f50c50>
[ 124 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4ede9d0>
[ 125 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c53983d0>
[ 126 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c5217ad0>
[ 127 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4f5f7d0>
[ 128 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4ea6550>
[ 129 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c5348290>
[ 130 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c51dbf10>
[ 131 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4f23250>
[ 132 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4e47450>
[ 133 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c4e73550>
[ 134 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4c388d0>
[ 135 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4bcaa90>
[ 136 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4b8eed0>
[ 137 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4b47650>
[ 138 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4b5d810>
[ 139 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4b0cc10>
[ 140 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4d85610>
[ 141 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4ace950>
[ 142 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4d85210>
[ 143 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4ace550>
[ 144 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4d4ac50>
[ 145 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4aa02d0>
[ 146 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4d25390>
[ 147 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4a5c6d0>
[ 148 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4d16dd0>
[ 149 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4a5c2d0>
[ 150 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4ced3d0>
[ 151 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4a31710>
[ 152 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c4904c10>
[ 153 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4e03290>
[ 154 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4ca9b50>
[ 155 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c49fe450>
[ 156 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4973f90>
[ 157 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4e36e90>
[ 158 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4cb9d10>
[ 159 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c49eee90>
[ 160 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c48c6810>
[ 161 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4de8a10>
[ 162 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4c76dd0>
[ 163 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4944490>
[ 164 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c48e66d0>
[ 165 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c4893790>
[ 166 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c465aad0>
[ 167 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c466ac90>
[ 168 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c462ed50>
[ 169 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c45e7850>
[ 170 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c45fba10>
[ 171 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c45aee10>
[ 172 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4824810>
[ 173 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c457b5d0>
[ 174 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4824410>
[ 175 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c450f790>
[ 176 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c47e9e50>
[ 177 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c453eb90>
[ 178 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c47b8590>
[ 179 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c44fd8d0>
[ 180 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c47b8190>
[ 181 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c44fd4d0>
[ 182 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c470a5d0>
[ 183 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4451250>
[ 184 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c43b03d0>
[ 185 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4893390>
[ 186 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4719a90>
[ 187 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4411650>
[ 188 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c43a0490>
[ 189 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c48a1790>
[ 190 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c46d2310>
[ 191 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4411250>
[ 192 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4375410>
[ 193 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4815050>
[ 194 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c469c350>
[ 195 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c43d6c90>
[ 196 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c43220d0>
[ 197 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c4331990>
[ 198 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c40fbc90>
[ 199 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4089810>
[ 200 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c404c290>
[ 201 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c400aa10>
[ 202 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c401bbd0>
[ 203 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3fdff90>
[ 204 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c42429d0>
[ 205 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3f99790>
[ 206 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c42425d0>
[ 207 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3fac950>
[ 208 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4215050>
[ 209 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3f60d50>
[ 210 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c41d3750>
[ 211 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3f1ea90>
[ 212 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c41d3350>
[ 213 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3f1e690>
[ 214 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c41a8790>
[ 215 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3eefad0>
[ 216 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c3dc1590>
[ 217 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c4e73150>
[ 218 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c41674d0>
[ 219 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3ead810>
[ 220 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3dd0110>
[ 221 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c4331590>
[ 222 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c41670d0>
[ 223 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3ead410>
[ 224 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3d955d0>
[ 225 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c4294190>
[ 226 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c413d510>
[ 227 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3e74e50>
[ 228 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3d44290>
[ 229 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c3d5f5d0>
[ 230 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3c76950>
[ 231 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3c76550>
[ 232 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3bcb2d0>
[ 233 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3b886d0>
[ 234 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3b882d0>
[ 235 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3b57710>
[ 236 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3d71790>
[ 237 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3b28450>
[ 238 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3d53750>
[ 239 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3b19e90>
[ 240 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3cd4150>
[ 241 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3aea490>
[ 242 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3cf0650>
[ 243 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3aa6c10>
[ 244 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3c85810>
[ 245 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3ab6dd0>
[ 246 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3cb6c10>
[ 247 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3a00210>
[ 248 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f94c3a39990>
[ 249 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c3a2dfd0>
[ 250 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3790d50>
[ 251 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c37f4d10>
[ 252 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3775e50>
[ 253 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c394c8d0>
[ 254 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3711c50>
[ 255 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c394c4d0>
[ 256 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c37217d0>
[ 257 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3920250>
[ 258 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c36e5250>
[ 259 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c38df650>
[ 260 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c387e3d0>
[ 261 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c36a29d0>
[ 262 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3633750>
[ 263 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c35b7650>
[ 264 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3983890>
[ 265 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c38df250>
[ 266 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3870e10>
[ 267 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c36b4b90>
[ 268 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c35c6910>
[ 269 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3545050>
[ 270 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3992750>
[ 271 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c38a2c90>
[ 272 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c37c2410>
[ 273 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c367afd0>
[ 274 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c35f8d10>
[ 275 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3508a90>
[ 276 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c39bfdd0>
[ 277 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c3780b90>
[ 278 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c35b7a50>
[ 279 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c353c110>
[ 280 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c34e9390>
[ 281 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c32b2890>
[ 282 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3294850>
[ 283 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3211990>
[ 284 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c3479410>
[ 285 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c322d790>
[ 286 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3466e50>
[ 287 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c323f950>
[ 288 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c343c450>
[ 289 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c31f6d50>
[ 290 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c33f9bd0>
[ 291 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c330c950>
[ 292 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c31b3a90>
[ 293 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c30c6810>
[ 294 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c3055190>
[ 295 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c34dadd0>
[ 296 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c3389d90>
[ 297 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c331fb10>
[ 298 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c31b3690>
[ 299 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c30c6410>
[ 300 ]  <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f94c303c110>
[ 301 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c34da050>
[ 302 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c33501d0>
[ 303 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c32e1f50>
[ 304 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c3106ad0>
[ 305 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c308be50>
[ 306 ]  <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f94c303ca90>
[ 307 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c344eed0>
[ 308 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c329e6d0>
[ 309 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c3055590>
[ 310 ]  <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f94c2fdd5d0>
[ 311 ]  <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f94c2ff7910>
[ 312 ]  <keras.layers.pooling.GlobalAveragePooling2D object at 0x7f94c2e41a10>
[ 313 ]  <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f94c2e41a90>
[ 314 ]  <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f94c2e41110>
```